# How to implement a timer in c?

Tags: c, linux

We want to add a timer to our C program under Linux platform.

We are trying to send the packets and we want to find out how many packets get sent in 1 minute. We want the timer to run at the same time as the `while` loop for sending the packet is being executed. For example:

```
    while(1)    
    {     
      send packets;    
    }
```

This loop will keep on sending the packets until ctrl-z is pressed. The timer should be used to stop the loop after 60 seconds.

Comment: Why not just fork() and make child process watch over parent?

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile int stop=0;

void sigalrm_handler( int sig )
{
    stop = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction sact;
    int num_sent = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sact.sa_mask);
    sact.sa_flags = 0;
    sact.sa_handler = sigalrm_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sact, NULL);

    alarm(60);  /* Request SIGALRM in 60 seconds */
    while (!stop) {
        send_a_packet();
        num_sent++;
    }

    printf("sent %d packets\n", num_sent);
    exit(0);
}
```

If loop overhead turns out to be excessive, you could amortize the overhead by sending N packets per iteration and incrementing the count by N each iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Just check the time on every iteration of the loop and when 1 minute has elapsed, count how many packets you have sent.

**Edit** changed to reflect what the question actually asks!

```
time_t startTime = time(); // return current time in seconds
int numPackets = 0;
while (time() - startTime < 60)
{
    send packet
    numPackets++;
}
printf("Sent %d packets\n", numPackets);
```

Comment: If you're benchmarking anything, it's not the best idea to be including your timing mechanism in the benchmark timings.

Comment: If it takes 100 seconds to send a packet, then this code will claim that one packet was sent, while in reality no packet was sent before the 60 seconds elapsed. This is misleading, I think you should add an additional timer check before increasing numPackets. Or alernatively, use on counter for started transmissions and another for finished transmissions.

Comment: @San Jacinto:  simple is beautiful.

Comment: @Lundin:  no it won't:  the packet is sent and then the counter is incremented.

Comment: I think Lundin's point is that there's nothing to show whether the loop terminated at exactly 60 seconds or not. To address this, you could record time() before the beginning of the loop and after loop termination so that the actual elapsed time can be computed and displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Can also check this http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html to set timers which will send signals to your process and you can stop the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the standard `time()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code snippet of itimer that can be used for different time intervals on C with linux platform:

```
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>

    void timer_handler (int signum)
    {
     static int count = 0;
     printf ("timer expired %d times\n", ++count);
    }

    int main ()
    {
        struct sigaction sa;
        struct itimerval timer;

        /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
        memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
        sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
        sigaction (SIGVTALRM, &sa, NULL);

        /* Configure the timer to expire after 1 sec... */
        timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
        /* ... and every 1000 msec after that. */
        timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
        /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is
        *    executing. */
        setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &timer, NULL);

        /* Do busy work. */
        while (1);
            sleep(1);
    }
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use wheetimer (and its variant) data structures to implement timers.

Answer (score -2):

man 3 sleep:

> NAME
>          sleep - Sleep for the specified number of seconds
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include < unistd.h >
>
> ```
>    unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
> ```

Comment: This doesn not what the asker wants.

Comment: @nightcracker Actually, it does. By creating a new thread and making it sleep for 60 seconds, you know that 60 seconds is up when the thread is done running. He really should not be inlining his timing code with his test code, so this answer is appropriate, even if it isn't the way I'd do it.

Comment: @Sac Jacinto: just no. Creating a thread like this to ping back to the original thread just to use sleep is such a lame excuse for a wrong solution. The OP should use a timer, not something that sleeps.

Comment: @nightcraker To each his own. Guess you'll have to send out the software police when elcuco does it :)

Comment: @SanJacinto: I'll sure do! And btw, it's nightcracker not nightcraker ^^

Comment: @nightcracker Oops! That was a typo. My Apologies. I hope that's not something insulting where you're from.

Comment: @SanJacinto: don't worry, it's not :)

Comment: sleep() can't be used to measure time. There are no guarantees that sleep() will give a context switch back to the sleeping thread after exactly 60 seconds. The only guarantee you have is that it will finish after _at least_ 60 seconds. And of course, Linux is no RTOS, so there are no accuracy guarantees for any form of timer.

Comment: @Lundin and yet when I measured it across several devices (ARM, i386, amd64) linux gave me less jittering then windows. Yes its not a RTOS, but its quite close, and most of the time it is "good enough"

Comment: horrible solution. As has been stated, this does not guarantee 60 seconds exactly. Testing on a few devices also doesn't prove much. You would need to do a lot of unit tests under different conditions, if this would be suitable.