# Timed C Program Loop

Tags: c, loops

I need to loop for a certain amount of time based on user input ( in C Program ).

Example: User says loop for 2 Minutes ( = 120 seconds).

```
while(time <= 2 Minutes)
{
    do something
}
```

How would I go about doing this in C? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: do you need to _loop_ or _wait_ for that amount of time ? If it's the later, then you want to look into `sleep(3)` and `usleep(3)` probably

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348318/creating-a-timer-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167949/how-to-use-timer-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189845/how-to-implement-a-timer-in-c

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/129580/how-to-use-timer-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform some operation as many times as possible within the specific period of time you can use [`time()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time):

```
time_t secs = 120; // 2 minutes (can be retrieved from user's input)

time_t startTime = time(NULL);
while (time(NULL) - startTime < secs)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly what I need! However, when I compile, I get this error:

"error: too few arguements to function 'time'."

Comment: @JakeZ: Yah, you should pass `NULL` to get the current time. I also added a link to man page of `time` function.

Comment: Is there anything for milliseconds too?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop.

Just take a [nap](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep). It will sleep for the amount of time and let the processor to do something more useful

Comment: I need to perform some operation as many times as possible within the specific period of time...thus napping is not an option for me!

Comment: You did not point that out in the question. Besides how long does the operation in the loop take. Perhaps it should periodically ask - Should I abort.